Modeling a chemical reaction when there is a catalyst
I'd like to construct potential energy surfaces (PES) for chemical reactions with and without the presence of a catalyst. Something like this

The closest paper that is https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14460.pdf, but despite the name they introduced some techniques to speed up / minimize the number of gates needed. Drawing the PES given the bond length and qubitizating to simulate the Hamilton are manageable, but I am still unsure how to do this with catalyst. In principal I think we need to model the ligand nut that require too many qubits. There may be better ways to do that
Could you give me any pointer :) thank you
